# what web services we can use to implement push notification in android devices instead of GCM?

Tags: android, rest, push-notification

GCM has size limitation. It can only send 4Kb data in a message. what ele web services we can use instead of GCM to implement push noification?

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass more than GCM allows in Notification payload. If you need to get more complicated data write your own server api and call it from your application.

Comment: can i use RESTful to implement push notification in my android application